# RxJS wait for second observable then retry original observable on error - TypeScript/Angular 2

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am fairly new to Angular 2, TypeScript and RxJS and I am creating a simple application that leverages the Salesforce Ajax Toolkit connections library.

I am trying to write a handler to catch when a token has expired any time a method from the connections library is called. I have created a service that essentially wraps the connections library to use observables. For example if we look at the insert function I have created my own wrapper function:

```
 public insert(object: sforce.SObject): Observable<any> {
   return new Observable(observer => {
   // successfully inserted the record
   let insertSuccess = (result) => {
     observer.next(result);
     observer.complete();
    }

    // An error occured inserting the record
    let insertError = (result) => {
      // This does not work yet
      if (result.faultcode.indexOf('INVALID_SESSION_ID') != -1) {
        this.refreshToken();
      }
      else {
          observer.error(result);
      }
    }

    let callback = { onSuccess: insertSuccess, onFailure: insertError };
    sforce.connection.create([object], callback);
  });
}
```

I have another function that refreshes the access token:

```
 public refreshToken(): void {
    this.loginService.login().subscribe(
        response => {

            Globals.SESSION_TOKEN = response.access_token;

            //initialize the salesforce connection 
            this.init(Globals.SESSION_TOKEN, this.loginService.AuthParams.SOAP_URL);
        },
        error => {

        }
    );
}
```

I essentially want the original `insert` function to wait for `refreshToken` to complete. If it is successful I want to retry the same insert again, otherwise I want the original insert observable to call `observer.error`.

I've looked into `retry` and `retryWhen`, however I haven't been able to figure out how to implement it to wait for the `refreshToken()` function to complete. Any guidance or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `catch` operator accepts a function which processes an error *and* the source `Observable`. This means that if you catch an error you can determine whether you want to resubscribe to the original source in the `catch` block:

```
 public insert(object: sforce.SObject): Observable<any> {
   return new Observable(observer => {
   // successfully inserted the record
   let insertSuccess = (result) => {
     observer.next(result);
     observer.complete();
    }

    // An error occured inserting the record
    let insertError = (result) => observer.error(result);


    let callback = { onSuccess: insertSuccess, onFailure: insertError };
    sforce.connection.create([object], callback);
  }).catch((err, source) => {
     if (err.faultcode.indexOf('INVALID_SESSION_ID') != -1) {
        //This waits for the refresh to complete and then resubscribes
        //to the source
        //If the refresh errors then it will skip the resubscribe
        return this.refreshToken().flatMapTo(source);
     }
     //Non-authentication error
     return Observable.throw(err);
  });
}
```

Then make your `refreshToken` function into something like so:

```
 public refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.loginService.login()
      .tap(response => {
        Globals.SESSION_TOKEN = response.access_token;

        //initialize the salesforce connection 
        this.init(Globals.SESSION_TOKEN, this.loginService.AuthParams.SOAP_URL);
      });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @paulpdaniels! Can you explain what tap does? `this.loginService.login` returns an `http.post`. I am getting the error `this.loginService.login(...).tap is not a function`

Comment: `tap` executes a side effect on events in the stream, while still letting them pass through. You will most likely have to include the operator using `import 'rxjs/add/operator/tap'`