# How do I intercept an unauthorised response with a dialog to enter a password and retry it?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-material2, angular2-observables

I'm building an app that has a backend with a simple authentication and a `GET` request. I want to show the user a dialog to re-enter their password when their authentication expires. When you fill in your password and click submit, I want to retry the original HTTP call and get the data within the original `Observable`. I would guess that this is possible, but I can't seem to find a way to start.

This question is similar:
[RxJS wait for second observable then retry original observable on error - TypeScript/Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602186/)

But I'm using `.pipe()` and `catchError` so I can subscribe to the function in my API service instead of a separate http call. I'm not sure what other information I should provide to make my question clear, but please let me know if there is anything else you need to know.

This is my current code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { Observable, ObservableInput } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs/Operators";
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { SessionExpiredComponent } from "./dialogs/session-expired/session-expired.component";
import "rxjs/add/observable/throw";
import { User } from "./classes/user";
import { Test } from "./classes/test";

const header = {
  withCredentials: true
};

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  user: User = null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private matDialog: MatDialog) {}

  private errorHandler() {
    return (err: any) => {
      let dialog = this.matDialog.open(SessionExpiredComponent, {
        data: { err: err, email: this.user.email, apiService: this },
      });
      return dialog.afterClosed();
//I want to return a retry of the original observable
    };
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): void {
    const formHeader = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    };
    this.http
      .post<User>(
        environment.backend + "auth/login",
        "email=" +
          encodeURIComponent(email) +
          "&password=" +
          encodeURIComponent(password),
        formHeader
      )
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
      });
  }

  getTests(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(
        environment.backend +
          "tests/query?accountId=" +
          this.user.defaultAccount,
        header
      )
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler()));
  }
}
```

This code works as-is, but doesn't retry the call when I enter my password and re-authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm able to link an `Observable` directly after another `Observable` by using `.flatMap()`. This means that the `errorHandler` looks like this:

```
private errorHandler(source: Observable<any>) {
    return (err: any) => {
      let dialog = this.matDialog.open(SessionExpiredComponent, {
        data: { err: err, email: this.user.email, apiService: this }
      });
      return dialog.afterClosed().flatMap(data => {
        return source.retry();
      });
    };
  }
```

After the dialog is closed, it returns a retry of the source `Observable`, which I need to pass into the `errorHandler` like this:

```
  getTests(): Observable<any> {
    let observable = this.http
      .get<any>(
        environment.backend +
          "tests/query?accountId=" +
          this.user.defaultAccount,
        header
      );
      return observable.pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler(observable)));
  }
```

And now my `getTests` function is an Observable that will:

- Get tests
- If that fails, show a password dialog to reconnect
- When the dialog is done (which means I re-authenticated), retry the HTTP call